# pro (a long) tempore

Tags: discussion, moderation

It's been nearly three years since I started as pro-tem moderator on this fabulous site, and I think it's time for me to step aside. The [job of a pro-tem](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) is supposed to be:

> - ...a temporary, short-term appointment...
> - ...provisional [...] until the community holds formal elections after the Beta period...

Because we've been in beta for [such a long time](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1817/biblical-hermeneutics), my role has extended far longer than the post was originally intended to last and possibly longer [than any other site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139374/166851) has ever been in beta? That's not an issue for elected moderators but pro-tems are appointed and aren't necessarily the people the community would chose to moderate.

I don't know how long we have left in beta. We're obviously [making progress](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/313/43), but I think it may be a while before we have enough active members to make an election meaningful. In the meantime I think someone else from the community should be given the privilege of ["Judiciously limiting your use of moderator powers to selectively prune and guide the community"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

Meanwhile I get a chance to re-join the *other* [great team of <s>18</s> 23](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/794/43) BH.SE "[moderators](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1817?phase=beta&users=reputation#tab-top)": the active users of the site. I've really appreciated the effort you've all put in editing, flagging, thrashing out site direction on meta and so on, and I hope I'm half as helpful as you are to the mods and the site.

It's been a pleasure working alongside Caleb and Dan recently, and I'm sure it'll continue to be a pleasure working with those two excellent moderators and friends, from the other side of the flag curtain :) It was also a pleasure working with Ray and Richard during their time and especially with Jon: he [moved on](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/622/43) to work with the Stack Exchange Community Team, but I believe he will always have a special interest in this site and our community. Thank you all very much.

---

tl:dr;

- Many thanks for putting up with me this long!
- Please support and encourage whoever is appointed pro-tem next.

Comment: i upvoted this, not because you're stepping back but because you've been a mod of conviction with a steady hand. you're a good man and have remained solid while on a rocky ship

Comment: @JackDouglas Thank you, Jack, for all your prodigious effort and especially for being "another POV" for some of us fringe wackos. I still recall you 'saved' my 1st posts when I was DV'd to oblivion and grossly misunderstood. Thank you, again, for all your patience, hard work, and technical savvy that makes a place like this work.

Comment: @user2479 you are welcome :) it's been a joy to see your work gaining more acceptance here

Comment: BH is nowhere close to being the longest running beta site. In fact [it's #24](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=beta&page=2) in line for that dubious distinction.

Comment: I wish you all the very best for the future and thanks for all your help in making BH an interesting and enjoyable site.

Comment: Thanks, Jack, for all the time and effort you've given to the community in this role.

Comment: @JackDouglas - almost didn't recognize you without your "♦". Must be a bit like taking off your sunglasses. B-) Thanks for all you brought/bring to BH.SE. (And welcome to Susan, too!)